# Making JPA work with Spring Framework on JBoss server

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

**Basis**

I am using Spring 2.5.6 and Hibernate 3.2.1 - because I have to deploy to a jboss 4.2.3 whose setup is not allowed to be disturbed (because the jboss server is built by a script, and the script is old but  no charter given to invest time to change it). So, no, cannot have private libraries for the app on JBoss.

I am a JPA by annotation person, not a hibernate XML person. So I am not going to change DTOs and mappings to using hibernate XML. Having to regress to Hibernate 3.2.1 from Hibernate 3.6 was already too much for me. I have hibernate auto detect my entity classes, and I will not be changing that.

**Problem**

I wrote a webapp which ran wonderfully with JPA and JAX-RS in JBoss 4.2.3 dev env. Now I have to fit it into Spring 2.5.6 framework.

So, I created the following **ApplicationContext.xml** ...

```
<bean id="propertyPlaceHolder" class="zzz.common.spring.config.ConfigPlaceholderConfigurer" >
    <property name="location" value="file:C:/config/bootstrap.properties"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager"> 
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="jpaTemplate" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTemplate"> 
  <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean" >
  <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="obamacare"/>    
</bean>
```

~

And this is the **persistence.xml**. Originally the property values were hardcoded during dev. But to turn them into production, their values have to be made into spring ${references}. The ${references} is read from file:C:/config/bootstrap.properties, and zzz.common.spring.config.ConfigPlaceholderConfigurer needs to set the user and password thro an auth service.

```
<persistence-unit name="obamacare" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <!-- Scan for annotated classes and Hibernate mapping XML files -->
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class, hbm" />

        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class"
            value="${zzz.common.sql.ConnectionPool.driverClass}" />
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url"
            value="${zzz.common.sql.ConnectionPool.url}" />

        <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="${zzz.common.sql.ConnectionPool.user}"/>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="${zzz.common.sql.ConnectionPool.password}"/>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.OracleDialect" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Obviously, the spring ${references} in the persistence XML is not working, because the entity manager is Null, because the The jdbc driver class is null. As well as the url and user and password.

I placed the following lines into the JAX-RS response code, which , where debugger shows that entityManager is null.

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;
```

**Questions**:

**Q1.**

What do I need to do to make the spring ${references} get injected into my persistence.xml properties?

**Q2.**

I tried to transfer the persisitence.xml properties into a datasource in ApplicationContext.xml.

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean" >
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="unit1"/>    
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

    <property name="driverClassName" value="${zzz.common.sql.ConnectionPool.driverClass}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${zzz.common.sql.ConnectionPool.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${zzz.common.sql.ConnectionPool.user}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${zzz.common.sql.ConnectionPool.password}"/>
</bean>
```

But JBoss start-up failed because ... DriverManagerDataSource is not writable, no setDatasource method or setDatasource method not accessible, blah, blah.

Why is the datasource not settable in DriverManagerDataSource? What do I need to do in an extension class to create a setDatasource method. What would I need to do inside that method?

Coould you suggest an alternative jdbc datasource that will allow setDatasource?

**Q3.**

Is there anything else I need to do or will spring framework automagically find the PersistenceContext annotation at entitymanager and then attempt to instantiate it?

**Q4.**

What does the bean jpaTemplate do? Why do I need it?

**Q5.**

If I transferred everything to ApplicationContext.xml, do I still have to keep a dummy placeholding persistence.xml around?

I need help. By either making DriverManagerDataSource work in ApplicationContext.xml or making ${references} work in persistence.xml.

Thank you all.

This is a follow up to the question I asked last week: [Setting JPA persistence properties dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11695291/setting-jpa-persistence-properties-dynamically).

Comment: " no charter given to invest time to change it" - there's your problem.  Find a charter.

Comment: Charter has to be collected from 250 institutions all over the world. Not just my boss or his boss.

Comment: OK, this guy says we shouldn't use PersistenceContext for webapps, because it is not thread-safe: http://weblogs.java.net/blog/ss141213/archive/2005/12/dont_use_persis_1.html

Comment: @BlessedGeek you can say the same thing about almost any other object - servlet's are supposed to be stateless, adding an instance to it, breaks that law, and breaks Thread Safety - unless you protected that object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Q1**

You can't AFAIK, Spring will only load the placeholder configuration into it's own managaed xml files

**Q2, Q3, Q5**

This [blog post](http://krams915.blogspot.co.uk/2011/10/spring-310rc1-jpa-entitymanagerfactory.html) talks about using [LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html) to do away with persistence.xml

**Q4**

This post talks about [not wanting to use JpaTemplate](http://blog.springsource.org/2006/08/07/using-jpa-in-spring-without-referencing-spring/) but still get the Spring goodness of Exception translation, etc.

Answer (score 2):

**Q4**
JpaTemplate is not really necessary anymore.  It is depecated.

**Q5**
If you only have one persistence unit, there is no need for persistence.xml with Spring.  You can use the LCEMFB property "packagesToScan" and reference the entity package directories.

NOTE: Do NOT use the "PersistenceUnit" property, it will override the "PackagesToScan"

[I've blogged about Spring Data JPA here](http://gordondickens.com/wordpress/2011/08/01/simpler-jpa-with-spring-data-jpa/)

Comment: So the PersistanceUnit in persitence.xml was the reason my packages didn't get scanned on JBoss? But, why does it work on Tomcat regardless?